# Use ASP.NET MVC routing parameters showing undefined in angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Url which is using asp.net MVC routing

```
http://localhost:23293/Exam?id=1
```

i want to access id parameter in angular js controller

```
aoeapp.controller('ExamController', function ($scope, examservice, $routeParams) {
$scope.exams = [];
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
alert($scope.id);
$scope.getAllexams = function (id) {

    examservice.getExamMaster(id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.exams = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, Xhr) {

        alert(Xhr);
    });
};
$scope.getAllexams(id);
});
```

so here $scope.id showing undefined

My mvc routing is just default routing

**Edit**
The angular routes

```
aoeapp.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.when('/', { 
        controller: 'HomeController', 
        templateUrl: 'Pages/Home.html' 
    }).when('/Exam/:id', { 
        controller: 'ExamController', 
        templateUrl: 'Pages/Exam.html' 
    }).when('/Test/:id', { 
        controller: 'TestController', 
        templateUrl: 'Pages/Test.html' 
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
});
```

Comment: Angular doesn't care about your server side routing. What are your _Angular_ routes?

Comment: ok , But if i am using angular routes than it is conflicting with MVC routing and it is not working

Comment: You can use routing on both sides but your Angular application only cares about Angular routes. Add your Angular routes to this question.

Comment: aoeapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {

            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'Pages/Home.html'

        })
    .when('/Exam/:id', {

        controller: 'ExamController',
        templateUrl: 'Pages/Exam.html'

    })
    .when('/Test/:id', {

        controller: 'TestController',
        templateUrl: 'Pages/Test.html'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'

    });

   

});

Comment: but problem is that angular routing is not working application accepting only mvc route ..... so i want to knw what to change in routemap

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where my Angular routes were routed to my MVC controllers. I fixed it using a catchall route:

Add this route to your `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Angular",
    url: "Exam/{*url}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Angular", action = "Index" }
);
```

With the following action in your `Controllers/AngularController.cs` file:

```
[Route("Exam/{*url}")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

This should intercept all calls to the `/Exam` and redirect them to your Angular router. You may have to play a litle with the `Route` attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with a different approach. I created a `ViewBag` variable to store the query string or the id, you can also use the `model`, and then pass it into an angular method. You can understand this more clearly by going through the code:

**Razor View**

```
<form name="ExamForm" ng-init="$scope.setQueryStringToScopeId(@ViewBag.Id)">
    ....
</form>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
aoeapp.controller('ExamController', function ($scope, examservice) {

    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.setQueryStringToScopeId = function(id) {
        $scope.id = id;
    };
    ....
});
```

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Exam()
{
    ViewBag.Id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    return View();
}
```

You can also use the query string directly in your `Razor View`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: if i do alert inside  $scope.setQueryStringToScopeId = function(id) {
        $scope.id = id;  alert( $scope.id ); 
    };  works fine inside function but outside this function again showing 0 value

Comment: I will have to see your code but once `$scope.setQueryStringToScopeId` is executed you can `alert($scope.id)` and it will work...